# Android calculator App crushed

Tags: android

I have a problem in my calculator app 
I try to call method but when I do that my app is crashing
I have the same method with `int` and with `double` but the `double` crashing (is the same call)

```
public void pressEquals(View v)
{
    String[] tar = tvResult.getText().toString().split(" ");

    String res = " ";
    double dRes = Double.valueOf(tar[0])+Double.valueOf(tar[2]);
    int iRes = Integer.valueOf(tar[0])+Integer.valueOf(tar[2]);
    if ( dRes == iRes)
        intcalc(iRes, tar);
    else
        doublecalc(dRes, tar);
}

public void intcalc(int num, String [] tar)
{
    int result = num;
    String res = " ";
    if(tar[1].equals("+"))
        res = tar[0] + " + " + tar[2] + " = " + result;
    else if(tar[1].equals("-"))
        res = tar[0] + " - " + tar[2] + " = " + result;
    else if(tar[1].equals("*"))
        res = tar[0] + " * " + tar[2] + " = " + result;
    else if(tar[1].equals("/"))
        res = tar[0] + " / " + tar[2] + " = " + result;
    tvResult.setText(res);
}
public void doublecalc(double num, String [] tar)
{
    double result = num;
    String res = " ";
    if(tar[1].equals("+"))
        res = tar[0] + " + " + tar[2] + " = " + result;
    else if(tar[1].equals("-"))
        res = tar[0] + " - " + tar[2] + " = " + result;
    else if(tar[1].equals("*"))
        res = tar[0] + " * " + tar[2] + " = " + result;
    else if(tar[1].equals("/"))
        res = tar[0] + " / " + tar[2] + " = " + result;
    tvResult.setText(res);
}
```

Comment: What is the error/stacktrace you are getting?

Comment: The error is important , check error in logcat .

Comment: Check is it array size ok, maybe you call index of non-existent element... Show us how you call these methods.